# Quanto cobrar em um site?

Tags: c#

Muito se é falado de como desenvolver uma aplicação web, um site ou até um e-commerce. Mas uma pergunta que acho que grande parte dos desenvolvedores tem é: "Quanto devo cobrar deste site?" 

Quanto devo cobrar em um site institucional? E em um e-commerce? E uma aplicação web?

Existe um cálculo no qual eu deva fazer antes de definir um valor a ser cobrado?
E a famosa manutenção? Como eu faço e quanto cobraria?

#### Resumindo

Eu sei que são muitas perguntas distintas, mas seguindo essa linha de raciocínio eu questiono:

**"Como e quanto cobrar um site ou uma aplicação web de meu cliente?"**

Comment: Cobre bem baratinho. Lembre-se sempre de que qualquer contratante tem um sobrinho "que sabe tudo de informática" que disse que é super simples fazer o site.

Comment: Quem quer pagar o mais barato e ter o mais fácil terá o real valor do serviço contratado. A minha pergunta não se baseia em saber fazer um site ou não pra depois cobrar, mas sim pra distinguir um meio justo de definir um preço para o meu serviço. Seja com base de complexidade nas linha de código, tipo de produto ou quantidade de linhas de código.

Comment: "Preço justo" é um conceito relativo. Pode-se considerar que é aquele que o desenvolvedor considere que remunera adequadamente seu trabalho mas pode ser bem menos que isso se, por exemplo, o desenvolvedor considerar que é mais importante conseguir um contrato com o cliente do que ser adequadamente remunerado "neste trabalho em especial".

Comment: Sua pergunta tem mérito, ao meu ver, mas somente na questão do cálculo do custo de projeto/desenvolvimento/manutenção. Quanto ao valor, é um assunto de marketing e administração, não programação. Acho que se formular outra pergunta focando no _custo_ do desenvolvimento, ela terá uma chance de ser aceita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma fórmula símples:

- precoMaximo = pesquise sobre o seu cliente, e tente determinar o máximo que ele pagaria (dica: pesquise sobre o mercado, e o que o seu cliente tem acesso desse mercado)
- precoMinimo = saiba o mínimo que você necessita (suas contas pessoais devem entrar aqui)

Tire a média, depois tire a média superior, e comece a negociar por aí. (ou seja, pegue o valor à 3/4 entre o mínimo e o máximo)

Você agora deve induzir o cliente a fechar em um preço perto da média, de 1/4 até 3/4.

Se fechar em um valor baixo, compense na manutenção. Se fechar a um valor mais alto, de uma folga para o cliente na manutenção.

Lembre-se, uma vez instalado o sistema, o cliente fica meio preso a você, portando seja caridoso no início, e tente obter mais do cliente depois.